# Use DrawingBrush to create two Vertical Lines

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a 50 x 50 square that has half of the rectangle white and the other half black (the lines going vertically instead of horizontally). I have the following code, but it is not filling the rectangle as expected. How do I make it 50% white and 50% black?

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle swatch = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
swatch.Width = 50;
swatch.Height = 50;

DrawingBrush blackBrush = new DrawingBrush();
GeometryDrawing backgroundSquare = new GeometryDrawing(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White,null,new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(25, 0, 50, 50)));
GeometryGroup gGroup = new GeometryGroup();
gGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(25, 0, 100, 100)));
GeometryDrawing checkers = new GeometryDrawing(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), null, gGroup);

DrawingGroup checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(backgroundSquare);
checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers);

blackBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;

blackBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
blackBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;

swatch.Fill = blackBrush;

sp_Thumbnails.Children.Add(swatch);
```

Comment: You want your rectangle to fill half with white brush and half with black brush right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple to have three sections just have one more GeometryDrawing object within your drawingGroup.
you can also configure the number of GeometryDrawing will be there within your drawingGroup as below.

Please see the generic solution to your problem that will display horizontal sections as per the groupCount value.

```
public void CreateRectangle(int groupCount)
        {
            Rectangle swatch = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
            swatch.Width = 50;
            swatch.Height = 50;
            double groupsize = 100 / groupCount;
            DrawingBrush blackBrush = new DrawingBrush();
            DrawingGroup checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
            //Considering 3 as groupCount
            List<SolidColorBrush> brushes = new List<SolidColorBrush>() { Brushes.Black, Brushes.White,Brushes.Red };
            double location = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
            {                
                GeometryDrawing drawing = new GeometryDrawing(brushes[i] , null,
                    new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, location,groupsize,groupsize)));
                checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(drawing);
                location += groupsize;
            }
            blackBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;
            swatch.Fill = blackBrush;

            brdrect.Children.Add(swatch);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To fill your rectangle half with black and half with white. I modified your code as below. This will create a rectangle with lines separating two sections vertically.

```
Rectangle swatch = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
            swatch.Width = 50;
            swatch.Height = 50;

            DrawingBrush blackBrush = new DrawingBrush();
            GeometryDrawing backgroundSquare = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.White, null,
                new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 25, 25)));
            GeometryGroup gGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            gGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(25, 0, 25, 25)));
            GeometryDrawing checkers = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, gGroup);

            DrawingGroup checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
            checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(backgroundSquare);
            checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers);

            blackBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;            
            swatch.Fill = blackBrush;

            brdrect.Children.Add(swatch);
```

If you want your sections to be spliced horizontally then you will need few changes in above code.
just modify the rectangle drawing creation section as below.

```
GeometryDrawing backgroundSquare = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.White, null,
                new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 25, 25)));
            GeometryGroup gGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            gGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 25, 25, 25)));
            GeometryDrawing checkers = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Black, null, gGroup);
```

Comment: This works for me. Do you have any insight into how to do 3 lines? I was thinking from this point it would be easy but I am still stuck.

Comment: If this solved your problem please upvote the answer.             Can you provide some more information on what you mean by 3 lines? you want three different sections in your rectangle or you want to have tiles behavior in 3 lines in your rectangle?

Comment: Three different sections - so instead of 50/50 its something like 33/33/33 (rounded to 100 of course). I need to read in some numbers and dynamically draw the colors.. so I could scale to more then 3 but I think that would be enough for me to figure it out